# MySQL database corrupted

Tags: mysql

My INNODB database corrupted somehow.I have no backups of that database.

When I click on the database tables in question they come up with:
(#1033 - Incorrect information in file: './resafari/properties.frm')

anyone have any solution for that ? please help me.

Comment: I would say first of all, make a manual copy of your mySQL data directory.

Answer (score 4):

First stop MySQL (and ensure there are no MySQL processes running), remove the ib_logfile* files from the mysql data directory, then start MySQL again. It will then recreate these files. These are the commands:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
cd /var/lib/mysql/
mv ib_logfile0 ~/
mv ib_logfile1 ~/
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The above moves the logfiles to the user's home folder just in case we needed to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently changed any your configuration through MySQL Administrator?

If so, it is possible that it has commented out all the settings in the my.ini file.

Have a look at this file using a plain text editor, and either manually correct any errors (remove the '#' comment markers) or copy over settings from a backup of my.ini.