# MYSQL: remove everything related to corrupted database

Tags: mysql, innodb

I had a corrupted database on my development environment that I could not access any more - probably due to a system crash. As I could not DROP the database (I can't remember why - doesnt matter any more now) I just deleted the databases folder in mysql/data.

This obviously was not a very good idea. After creating a new database with the same name, there are still some tablespace definitions somewhere in the database. When I try create new tables I get following error:

Tablespace for table '`database_name`.`table_name`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

Is there a decent way to get rid of all references/indexes/tablespace information for the given database? When I try to DROP the newly created Database with the same name, I get:
"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183645/mysql-database-corrupted

Comment: Thanks I tried several things but I want to delete the whole database, not just a single table and I am not interested in recovering any data either.

Answer (score 0):

when you get to a situation like that, the best thing to do is:

1. backup your database
2. delete entire database
3. restore your database from backup

Comment: I did delete the database but there were still tablespace entries aso. In the end I reinstalled the whole mysql server to fix it...what a waste of time though.

Comment: Yes, that happens. You shouldn't mess with MySQL files through the file system...  I've learned that lesson the hard way, too :)

Answer (score 0):

For each table run these two queries:

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename DISCARD TABLESPACE;
    ALTER TABLE tablename IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

If there are too many tables just write a script to loop through them using SHOW TABLES and then the two queries above.